# How to delete file on Windows Remote Server?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to delete specific file on Windows Remote Server using Python?

I'm able to connect to remote Windows Server using WMI, but not sure how to delete file remotely on windows server.

Comment: Do you have some code that you have tried? Get any errors? Please include more info in the question.

Comment: import wmi
import win32
import os
c = wmi.WMI ('server name',user='user name',password='password')


dir_name = "c:/test/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".txt"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))

Comment: error is i'm not able to delete file after remote connection...

Comment: All the commands from the `os` module that you use act on your local machine.

Comment: Here's a link to the official docs for wmi. They have a tutorial and lot's of example on to use it. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#examples

Comment: Thanks Guys!, still i'm not able to find the way to delete file on remote machine

Comment: what is the option to delete file in windows remote machine, i tried with remove it's not working...